# What to enter in context of dialog in onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, dialog, dialogfragment

I am trying to make a unit converter by following a youtube video. The problem is that he's doing all that in his main activity while I'm doing all that in a fragment. The errors are in the java class of the fragment `UnitConverterFragment.java` as

```
public class UnitConverterFragment extends Fragment {


    TextView convertFromDropdownTextView, convertToDropdownTextView, conversionRateText;
    EditText amountToConvert;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    Dialog fromDialog;
    DialogFragment toDialog;
    Button convertButton;
    String convertFromValue, convertToValue, conversionValue;
    String[] unit = {}; //TODO
    //end


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unit_converter, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //start
        convertFromDropdownTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.convert_from_dropdown_menu);
        convertToDropdownTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.convert_to_dropdown_menu);
        convertButton = view.findViewById(R.id.conversionButton);
        conversionRateText = view.findViewById(R.id.conversionRateText);
        amountToConvert = view.findViewById(R.id.amountToConvertValueEditText);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String i : unit) {
            arrayList.add(i);
        }
        convertFromDropdownTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fromDialog = new Dialog(UnitConverterFragment.this);
                fromDialog.setContentView(R.layout.from_spinner);
                fromDialog.getWindow().setLayout(650, 800);
                fromDialog.show();

                EditText editText = fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                ListView listView = fromDialog.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UnitConverterFragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            }
        });
        //end
    }
}
```

The `MainActivity.java` is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //start

    //end

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start

        // end

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null)  {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_unit_converter:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new UnitConverterFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_contact:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contacting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sharing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

The error I get is in the `OnClickListener` at the last of `UnitConverterFragment.java`. It says it requires a context. I'm really new to this so probably making a big blunder. I was watching [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_pSMcxShJ0&ab_channel=VinsonDevelopers).

Comment: change this line of code...................... fromDialog = new Dialog(requireActivity()); ........ you are passing current context which is fragmentContext itself but you need to pass parent context.

Comment: fixed the error. thanks a lot <3

Comment: the ArrayAdapter is having an issue too. it says can't resolve constructer

Comment: ArrayAdapter is working fine but now problem is in toDialog. It says it must be a DialogFragment but when I make it that it says int is required. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are passing the current context  **this**  which is fragmentContext itself inside Dialog but you need to pass the parent context. You, can do something like the below:

```
....
...
convertFromDropDownTextView.setOnClickListener(...){
 ...
 fromDialog = new Dialog(requirActivity());
 ....
 //And your ArrayAdapter should be like below:
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);
....
}
```

Comment: this worked but now I have problem with toDialog statement.

Comment: toDialog ?? where are you using it. you have only defined it.

Comment: how can I send you the whole code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70786817/what-to-put-in-dialogfragment

Comment: why do you wanna use dialogFragment, you can use Dialog as you have used above.

Comment: when I used dialog it said dialog fragment is expected

Comment: Incompatible types. Found: 'android.app.Dialog', required: 'androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment'
This error is shown when I use as Dialog only

Comment: oh no wait smh. my bad. when declaring variables I declared fromDialog as Dialog and toDialog as DialogFragment. After reading the errors again and again I realized that why its saying DialogFragment when I only type Dialog. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the great help and time <3

Comment: welcome. u can upvote, if possible.

Comment: I would love to but I need atleast 15 reputation :( How to increase that btw? so I can upvote yours. I marked ✔️ tho